# opLatencies mongodb metric

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently retrieving some of the MongoDB metrics and display on a dashboard. there is a metrics called opLatencies, which I find it hard to understand.

Attached the link -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/command/serverStatus/#mongodb-serverstatus-serverstatus.opLatencies

Can someone please enlighten me, what value is opLatencies is capturing? It says "A 64-bit integer giving the total combined latency in microseconds" in the documentation, but what is 64-bit integer?